# Good resources to study colloquial speech

Tags: vocabulary, resources, study-technique

I am have been studying for awhile and am trying to become more natural in my writing and speaking. After speaking and texting to a few native Korean speakers they have commented my style is very "textbook."
Are there any resources that anyone can recommend to enhance my slang and conversational knowledge.

Also 반말 is ok for resources I am close enough to these friends where using it would not be considered rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dramas or sitcoms featuring conversations between young peers, a la "Friends", may be a good source. "내일 지구가 망해버렸으면 좋겠어" (So Not Worth It: https://www.netflix.com/title/81194153) comes to my mind.